# Facebook get data wrong,use the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit

When use the Graph API Explorer to visit https://graph.facebook.com/me/home ,sometimes get 4 page data (limit=25), sometimes get 2 page data (limit=25), why it has so big difference , the interval between two visits less than 3 seconds. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience with FB API when it comes to returning result for an API call, FB is bit inconsistent. The problem being faced by you can be attributed to several reasons. One of the reason may be the type of load the FB server is experiencing at that particular time. Note you are not the only user at that point making request to FB Server, There are hundreds of App doing the same at that time. So best option is to use **pagination while processing the call back** and also try increasing the limit that you are specifying it may not be big help but it will some what improve the results. Hope this helps.